# Questions about using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Am new to Azure and reviewing all the different services offered. Looking at Azure Data Factory to process various file types eg. XLS, JSON, CSV that range in size from 500KB to 5MB and contain order data and details for an existing Db. There is a "significant" amount of mapping from one structure to another with complex hierarchies for the final destination table(s)

Questions:

- Can Azure Data Factory be used in a Dev/Test subscription
- I see you can author ADF pipelines in VS 2019 but can you debug them also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually we separate the environments by creating separate Resource groups pertaining to each environment.
   Dev RG : for Dev env
   Test RG : for Test Env
   UAT RG : for UAT
   Prod Rg : For Prod

In Dev RG , since that being the dev environment ; the resources created are of lower tiers for cost savings. But there is no concept of tiers in ADF and the cost is based on execution of pipelines, so we keep the pipelines disabled in lower subscriptions.

So to answer, you can create ADF in any subscriptions and any RGs but universally the name should be unique.

2. Based on my understanding in VS 2019, the ADF project is for ADF v1 which is on the verge of deprecation.
   ADFV2 does not have a plugin for Visual Studio, most of the effort has been on the UX side. MSFT recommends you to use ADF UI as your development tool, where you can define your workflow easily and validate your changes.